# How do I use the jpa/hibernate annotation mapping to Set<Entity> and the Entity is composite primary key

Tags: java, spring, entity-framework, hibernate, jpa

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity(name = "users")
@ToString
@Table(name = "users")
@Embeddable
public class User implements UserDetails{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id",unique=true)
    private Long id;
    @OneToMany
    @Cascade({CascadeType.ALL })
    @JoinTable(name = "users_authorities")
    private Set<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities;
}
```

This is my `User.java`,and have a porperty `private Set<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities`. I want use jpa/hibernate mapping to another Entity `SimpleGrantedAuthority`.

```
@Data
@Entity(name = "authorities")
@Embeddable
@Table(name = "authorities", uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"authority","username"})})
class SimpleGrantedAuthority implements GrantedAuthority {
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "authority")
    private String authority;
    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;
}
```

This is `SimpleGrantedAuthority .java`,How do I write the correct annotation to map `Set<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities;` to `SimpleGrantedAuthority.java`above `private Set<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities;`

```
Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: com.as.backend.antscience.entity.SimpleGrantedAuthority
```

Comment: No class can have BOTH `@Entity` and `@Embeddable` so remove whichever you aren't going to use. Compound identity requires fields to be marked as `@Id`, which you havent done, and optionally `@IdClass`. But then all of that depends if it is an entity or embeddable

Answer (score 0):

if you need an express composite key in JPA , you have to write as below.
first , define composite key as class and put a @Embeddable annotation.
and define that Id class as member of entitiy class and put @EmbeddedId

```
@Data
@Entity(name = "authorities")
@Embeddable
@Table(name = "authorities", uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"authority","username"})})
class SimpleGrantedAuthority implements GrantedAuthority {

    @EmbeddedId
    private Id id;

    @Embeddable
    @EqualsAndHashCode
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @Data
    public static class Id implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Column(name = "authority")
        private String authority;

        @Column(name = "username")
        private String username;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`@JoinColumns` annotation is probably what you are looking for.

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/JoinColumns.html